# Clicar em um link HTML e direcionar para um ID específico do banco de dados

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Boa tarde pessoal!

Gostaria de que quando eu clicasse em uma tag a HTML, me levasse ao link content/id

Por exemp.: se eu clicar no titulo do post 1, me direcionasse para o link content/1, se eu clicasse em titulo do post 2, me levar para content/2, assim por diante...

No momento, só consigo ir ao link manualmente pela URL. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Meu banco de dados:

```
export const dataFake = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Titulo do Post 1",
        "description": "teste post 1!",
        "photoCover": "https://64bdeaeb91c0a312d5f9537b--superlative-dusk-ea107d.netlify.app/posts-blog/assets/img5.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Titulo do post 2",
        "description": "Teste do post 2!",
        "photoCover": "https://64bdeaeb91c0a312d5f9537b--superlative-dusk-ea107d.netlify.app/posts-blog/assets/img2.png"

    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Titulo do post 3",
        "description": "Teste do post 3",
        "photoCover": "https://64bdeaeb91c0a312d5f9537b--superlative-dusk-ea107d.netlify.app/posts-blog/assets/img3.png"
    },  
    {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "Titulo do post 4",
        "description": "Teste do post 4",
        "photoCover": "https://64bdeaeb91c0a312d5f9537b--superlative-dusk-ea107d.netlify.app/posts-blog/assets/img4.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "Titulo do post 5",
        "description": "Teste do post 5",
        "photoCover": "https://64bdeaeb91c0a312d5f9537b--superlative-dusk-ea107d.netlify.app/posts-blog/assets/img5.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "title": "Titulo do post 6",
        "description": "Teste do post 6",
        "photoCover": "https://64bdeaeb91c0a312d5f9537b--superlative-dusk-ea107d.netlify.app/posts-blog/assets/img6.png"
    }
]
```

Meu home-component (só uma parte p n ficar mt grande)

````
<div class="main">

    <app-card
        Id="3"
        noticeImage="https://64bdeaeb91c0a312d5f9537b--superlative-dusk-ea107d.netlify.app/posts-blog/assets/img1.png"
        cardTitle="Titulo Do Post 1"
        descriptionNotice="Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati accusantium quo tempore eum exercitationem.

        "
    >
        
    </app-card> ```

[Meu site como exemplo][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtf4Y.png
````

Comment: Dá uma pesquisada por rotas, nas doc do Angular tem o que precisa, aqui: https://angular.io/guide/router e aqui: https://angular.io/api/router/Route

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como está a sua estrutura. Seria bom vc estudar um pouco de rotas no angular para ajudar. Mas vamos lá. No seu:
app.component.routing.ts, deve existir a rota e o componente do "Content" tanto para criar um novo como para edição/visualização.

Exemplo:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'content/add', component: ContentAddComponent }, // Novo
  { path: 'content/:id', component: ContentDetailComponent }, // Edição/visualização
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRouting { }
```

Você deve colocar na sua rota(path) o ":id" para declarar que nessa rota vai passar um identificador.

Caso esteja usando modulo para carregar os componentes no app.component.routing.ts seria algo assim.
Exemplo:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'Content', title: 'Content',
    loadChildren: () => import('./SuaRotaDoModulo/content.module').then((m) => m.ContentModule),
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

...
export class AppRouting { }
```

Você tem que carregar uma nova rota no ContentModule.

Exemplo: content.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
imports seus componentes.
import { contentRouting } from './content.routing'; // Carrega suas novas rotas do content.routing.ts

@NgModule({
  imports: [contentRouting], // Nova rota.
  declarations: [
    ContentAddComponent,
    ContentDetailComponent,
    ContentListComponent,
  ]
})
export class ContentModule { }
```

Seu content.routing.ts;

```
...
const contentRouting: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: ContentListComponent, // Através de modulo automaticamente ja entra nesta lista.
  },
  {
    path: 'add', component: ContentAddComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:id', component: ContentDetailComponent,
  },
];
export const contentRouting = RouterModule.forChild(contentRouting);
```

Você deve colocar na sua rota(path) o ":id" para declarar que nessa rota vai passar um identificador.

Em seu ContentDetailComponent.ts vc deve pegar o id desta forma:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'content-detail',
  templateUrl: './content-detail.html'
})
export class ContentDetailComponent {
  private yourId: string = "";
  @Input() set id(id: string) { this.yourId = id; }

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.categoryId = params['id'];
    });
    
    console.log(this.yourId)
  }
}
```

Lembrando que para acessar nova rota vc deve utilizar Router, na lista onde mostra os posts e passar o id:

Se for botão:

<button name="botao" class="btn-primary" [routerLink]="['content/detail/{{seuId}}']"
routerLinkActive="router-link-active">POST 1

Se for metodo:

```
<button name="botao" class="btn-primary" (click)="eventIrParaRota(seuId)">POST 1</button>

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

    eventIrParaRota(seuId: any){
        this.router.navigate([`content/detail/${seuId}`]);
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Primeiro, você precisa adicionar uma classe ou um atributo data ao elemento HTML que contém o título do post para que você possa identificá-lo facilmente e associá-lo ao ID do post correspondente. Vamos usar o atributo data-id para isso:

```html
<div class="main">
    <app-card
        data-id="1" <!-- Adicione o atributo data-id com o ID do post -->
        noticeImage="https://64bdeaeb91c0a312d5f9537b--superlative-dusk-ea107d.netlify.app/posts-blog/assets/img1.png"
        cardTitle="Titulo Do Post 1"
        descriptionNotice="Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati accusantium quo tempore eum exercitationem."
    ></app-card>
</div>
```

Em seguida, você pode adicionar um evento de clique aos elementos que têm esse atributo data-id e, quando clicados, redirecionar para a página content/id. Aqui está um exemplo de como fazer isso usando JavaScript puro:

```js
// Obtém todos os elementos com o atributo data-id
const postElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]');

// Adiciona um ouvinte de evento de clique a cada elemento
postElements.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Obtém o valor do atributo data-id (que é o ID do post)
        const postId = element.getAttribute('data-id');
        
        // Redireciona para a página content/id
        window.location.href = `content/${postId}`;
    });
});
```

Coloque esse código JavaScript no seu arquivo JavaScript principal ou dentro de uma tag  no seu HTML após a definição dos elementos com data-id. Certifique-se de que ele seja executado após o carregamento do DOM.

Dessa forma, quando você clicar nos títulos dos posts, o JavaScript redirecionará automaticamente para a página content/id correspondente ao ID do post. Certifique-se de que sua estrutura de diretórios e roteamento do servidor também estejam configurados para lidar com essas URLs.